# having trouble with bog standard openldap server db

Tags: fedora, openldap

I am having trouble getting an "out of the box" openldap server working.

The examples on the openldap site still refer to the slapd.conf file, but the install does not make that.

if I start the server (service slapd start) I do not get any errors, but cannot connect

ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

anyone have a simple howto for v2.4 ? 
I am on fedora15, installed openldap-servers and clients via yum.
I have phpldapadmin installed that I can try and connect with once I can get the command line working

a couple comments.

I found a reference to starting the server manually, via /usr/sbin/slapd -d -1 
instead of service slapd start.

Doing that showed me some debugging and I saw an error that a directory did not exist:
/var/openldap-data

I created that and then starting via /usr/sbin/slapd -d -1 actually does something now.

So, my questons at the moment are:

1. why does 
   ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts 
   work after manual slapd and not as a service?
2. Should it be using /var/openldap-data ? (I never specified that location.)

---

further comment / question:

the ldap server seems to be running fine when started via 
slapd -d -1 &

but the command
service slapd start
responds with OK but then does not start.

How can I tell what the problem is?  it does not seem to produce any error messages that I can see... is there a log somewhere that would show the error?

Comment: Please edit your question if you have more informations. Don't use the comment function for this.

Comment: moved comments into the main text.  thanks Thomas.